# Python's sh module - Running 'source' command

Tags: python

When using python's [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module, 
I would like to run a 'source' builtin command.

But I can't run it, because sh should have a binary as parameter.

How can I run builtin commands with sh module?

```
# source ./test.sh

sh.source('./test.sh') # wrong usage
sh.Command('source') # wrong usage
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're preferring `sh` as appropriate tool for the job here, as opposed to `subprocess.Popen('source test.sh', shell=True)`?

Comment: ...btw, I'd argue (have argued in the past, will argue again in the future) that `sh` is misleadingly named, since it doesn't actually invoke a shell at all. It's no surprise, given its name, that one would *expect* it to have access to the builtin commands available in `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To invoke `sh -c "source hello"` via the Python `sh` module (ignoring that `sh` is not guaranteed to support the `source` command at all -- the POSIX-compliant equivalent is [`. hello`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot)):

```
sh.sh('-c', 'source test.sh')
```

---

That said, consider using `subprocess.Popen()` instead, which contains far less magic and thus behaves more predictably:

```
# ...if hardcoding the script to source in your Python code
# ...because shell=True uses /bin/sh instead of bash, use . instead of source
subprocess.Popen('. ./test.sh', shell=True)

# ...otherwise:
# ...because shell=True uses /bin/sh instead of bash, use . instead of source
subprocess.Popen(['. "$@"', './test.sh'], shell=True)
```

When an array is passed to the first argument of `subprocess.Popen`, the first argument is treated as the source to run, and subsequent arguments became `$1`, `$2`, etc. during operation of that script, allowing the combination of an array of string literals with `/bin/sh` invoked via the `shell=True`.

---

**However: The intent and purpose behind sourcing content into a shell is generally to modify that shell's state.** With either `sh.sh` or `subprocess.Popen()`, the shell only lasts as long as that single Python function call's invocation, so no state persists to future `sh` or `subprocess` calls, making it unlikely that any of these uses will actually accomplish your goals at hand.

What you *really* want is probably more like this:

```
sh.sh('-c', '. ./test.sh; do-something-else-here')
```

...where your `do-something-else-here` depends on changes to the shell and its environment made by `source ./test.sh`.

Comment: It works well except sh.sh -> sh.bash. Thank you very much.

Comment: In case of subprocess.Popen, I should add executable = "/bin/bash".

Comment: @user3381542, if your script is written to be sourced by bash, it should use a `.bash` extension rather than `.sh` (which implies compatibility with any POSIX sh compliant shell).